# How to validate Israeli phone number?

Tags: c#, regex, validation, phone-number

I need a validation expression for a  phone number field  like  `09-8222333`.
 I tried to use `#^0\d([\d]{0,9})([-]{0,9})\d{7}$#` , but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

here: https://regex101.com/r/jiSGUV/1

or just copy the regex:`/^(?:(?:(\+?972|\(\+?972\)|\+?\(972\))(?:\s|\.|-)?([1-9]\d?))|(0[23489]{1})|(0[57]{1}[0-9]))(?:\s|\.|-)?([^0\D]{1}\d{2}(?:\s|\.|-)?\d{4})$/`

Answer (score 1):

I guess the `0` at the begining in mandetory, so you can use following regex: `0\d-\d{7}`
check in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kA9tU4/1).

`\d` means [0-9] and `{num}` means exatly `num` times repeat

Answer (score 1):

`0\d-\d{7}` is correct.

You can try `\b0\d-\d{7}\b` to avoid matching "09-8222333" in "3209-8222333435".

Use `\b0\d[- ]\d{7}\b` for numbers with the space instead of dash, like "09 8222333".

Use `\b((0\d[- ]\d{7})|(0\d[- ]\d{3}[- ]\d{4}))\b` to add support for numbers separated after first three symbols with ether dash or space like "06 455 3535 or 04 242-3424".

Learn regex at http://regexr.com/ it's about javascript regexes but true for c# also.
See c# examples at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_regular_expressions.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should probably work:

```
/[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7}/
```

`[0-9]{2}` Will match any number between `0` `and` 9 exactly two times, `-` will match a single hyphen character and then `[0-9]{7}` will match any number between `0` and `9` exactly `7` times.

You can also use the `\d` digit identifier as you had in your question to replace the `[0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

For android

```
public static boolean validateTelAndMobileNo(String mobileNo){
    //String test = "00911234567891";
    return  !(!mobileNo.matches("(00972|0|\\+972)[5][0-9]{8}") && !mobileNo.matches("(00970|0|\\+970)[5][0-9]{8}") && !mobileNo.matches("(05[0-9]|0[12346789])([0-9]{7})") && !mobileNo.matches("(00972|0|\\+972|0|)[2][0-9]{7}"));
}
```

for VB.net

```
Public Function validateMobileNo(m As String) As boolean
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m) Then Return false

    return not (Not Regex.IsMatch(m, "(00972|0|\\+972)[5][0-9]{8}") AndAlso Not Regex.IsMatch(m, "(00970|0|\\+970)[5][0-9]{8}") AndAlso Not Regex.IsMatch(m, "(05[0-9]|0[12346789])([0-9]{7})") AndAlso Not Regex.IsMatch(m, "(00972|0|\\+972|0|)[2][0-9]{7}")) 
End Function
```

This will validate mobile numbers and telephne numbers in Israel and Palestine
you can adjust to remove Palestinian mobiles and land telephones easly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex

```html
cellular israeli regex
/^05\d([-]{0,1})\d{7}$/

all numbers israel
/^0\d([\d]{0,1})([-]{0,1})\d{7}$/

Update one Regex for all Isrealy numbers

^\+?(972|0)(\-)?0?(([23489]{1}\d{7})|[5]{1}\d{8})$
```

The answer is based on Wassem's Blog article, which you can read [here](https://was955.wordpress.com/2016/12/25/israel-phone-number-regex/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Israeli phone number regex with the following israeli prefixes: 02-09 {7}, 05 {8}, 07 {8}:

`^0?(([23489]{1}[0-9]{7})|[57]{1}[0-9]{8})+$`

(This regex is match in Israel area only,for out of israel areas you should replace the 0 number at the beggigng of the regex with 972 numbers)

Answer (score -3):

this covers all phone numbers including landline and the 071,072,073,074,075,076,077 prefixes as well:

```
^\+?(972|0)(\-)?0?(([23489]{1}\d{7})|([71,72,73,74,75,76,77]{2}\d{7})|[5]{1}\d{8})$
```

Comment: This looks like a beginner regex from someone who has not yet learned what square brackets mean. Perhaps review the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) which contains a brief explanation of this common beginner mistake.

Comment: The fragment `[71,72,73,74,75,76,77]` is equivalent to `[,1-7]`. The `{1}` after two of the classes is unnecessary. The rest of the regex looks over complicated.